# Imputing the missing observations with series mean for panel data in R

Tags: r

I have a panel data that contains some missing values for a number of variables. I want to impute the missing data with series mean for panel data. I tried to use the following code, but I do not know how to ask r to do the calculation by taking into account the year and id or country.

The following code is a trial to impute the missing value for one variable. **My goal is to do this step for all variables.

```
my_data$V1[is.na(my_data$V1)] <- mean(my_data$V1,na.rm = TRUE)
```

head(my_data)

```
year   id    V1    V2
2000   AA         
2001   AA         
2002   AA    2     2
2003   AA    3     3
2000   BB    4     4
2001   BB         
2002   BB    3     3
2003   BB        
2000   CC    2     2     
2001   CC    3     
2002   CC    3     3       
2003   CC         
2000   DD          4
2001   DD          2
2002   DD          
2003   DD
```

How can I deal with the missing value by calculating the mean for the missing values?

It does not have to be the code I put here, if you have another method or way, please add it here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base R solution

```
my_data$V1<-ave(my_data$V1,my_data$id,FUN=function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), mean(x,na.rm=TRUE), x))
```

This is for applying it to all columns.

```
for (i in 3:ncol(my_data)){
  my_data[,i] <- ave(my_data[[i]],my_data$id,FUN=function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), mean(x,na.rm=TRUE), x))}
```

This is a solution without using loop

```
my_data[, 3:ncol(my_data)] = apply(my_data[, 3:ncol(my_data)], 2, function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), mean(x,na.rm=TRUE), x))
```

Comment: Thank you XXavier. I tried your code, it did work 'very good'. But it seems r calculated the mean for the whole column and added the same result in every cell with NA. How can we fix or update the code to tell R to look at the available values in a particular id during the data years.

Comment: Here is the code for creating a similar dataset `my_data <- data.frame("year" = c(2000,  2001,  2002,  2003,  2000,  2001,  2002,  2003,  2000,  2001,  2002,  2003,
  2000,  2001,  2002,  2003),"id" = c('AA', 'AA', 'AA', 'AA',  'BB', 'BB', 'BB', 'BB', 'CC', 'CC' , 'CC','CC', 'DD', 'DD', 'DD', 'DD'),
"v1"=c( NA, NA, 1, 8, 4, NA, 5, NA,  6, NA, 9, 4, 5, NA, NA, NA),
"v2"=c( NA, NA, 2, 3, 4, NA, 5, NA,  6, NA, 9, NA, 5, NA, 3,8))`

Comment: Here is the result i got for volumn v1. `4.500000, 4.500000 , 1.000000 , 8.000000 , 4.000000,  4.500000,  5.000000,  4.500000,  6.000000,  6.333333, 
9.000000,  4.000000,  5.000000,  5.000000,  5.000000, 5.000000` . Isn't this the output you wanted to see? For this data what output were you expecting if it is different?

Comment: Yes, I tired the first code on one of the variables in my data and I got the output I wanted to see. I will use the other code to apply it to all columns. For this data, I was expecting the same output you showed above. Thanks.

Comment: When I tried to use the second suggested code on the data above to apply it to all columns, I got the following messages `Warning messages:
1: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'avg'. 
2: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'avg'. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Please run the updated code for all columns. I am assuming the first two columns are year and ID. If you have more columns in the beginning that you do not want to impute please change this part `3:ncol(my_data)` of the code.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with aid of package `dplyr`.

```
my_data <- tibble::tribble(
  ~year, ~id, ~V1, ~V2,
  2000,  "AA", NA,  NA,   
  2001,  "AA", NA,  NA,           
  2002,  "AA",  2,   2,
  2003,  "AA",  3,   3,
  2000,  "BB",  4,   4,
  2001,  "BB", NA,  NA,       
  2002,  "BB",  3,   3,
  2003,  "BB", NA,  NA,        
  2000,  "CC",  2,   2,     
  2001,  "CC",  3,  NA,    
  2002,  "CC",  3,   3,       
  2003,  "CC",  NA, NA,       
  2000,  "DD",  NA,  4,
  2001,  "DD",  NA,  2,
  2002,  "DD",  NA,  NA,   
  2003,  "DD",  NA,  NA  
)

library(dplyr)
my_data <- my_data %>% group_by(year, id) %>% mutate(avg = mean(V1, na.rm=T))
my_data$V1[is.na(my_data$V1)] <- my_data$avg[is.na(my_data$V1)]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply and input. I tried the above codes but that did not work. I received the following message `Warning message:
In merge.pisa.WDI$all_ave_math[is.na(merge.pisa.WDI$all_ave_math)] <- merge.pisa.WDI$avg :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`

Comment: grouping by `year` and `id` doesn't seem to be terribly useful...

Comment: Many thanks. I tried the code and it did work. I was able to receive some values for the missing data for the variable I selected in my code, but the results or means is not a reflection of the available values for a given country and year.

Comment: I see what your code does; the code takes the available values and creates a mean and then applies it to all years within the same country or id. But I want to keep the available values or data as they are and use them to create means for the missing data that is above, below, or in-between.

Comment: I am not sure what above, below, or in-between means?

Comment: If you want to calculate average for id over years just remove `year` from `group_by()`.

Comment: The codes you provided works but the group_by() does not do anything different. Still the same results with `year` or without inside `group_by()`.

Comment: Are the example data your actual data? If you don't have enough data points to calculate mean, there still will be NA. With `my_data <- my_data %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(avg = mean(V1, na.rm=T))` NA for AA should be replaced by 2.5, but NAs for DD will remain there as there are no points to calculate mean from. For these, you can still use `mean(my_data$V1,na.rm = TRUE)`.

Comment: The given example is not my actual data. My actual data is large with 55 variables and many observations. When I run the codes you suggested on the data above, all NAs get replaced with one value only and that is 2.857143. What you described is what I want to get to.

Answer (score 0):

In this code you iterate over all Ids and all columns, replacing NA values for the correct means for each Id.

```
for(id in unique(matriz$id))
{
  for(i in 3:ncol(matriz))
  {
    my_data[is.na(my_data[,i]),i] <- mean(my_data[which(my_data$id == id & my_data$year <= '2003'),i],na.rm = TRUE)
  }
}
```

As your data starts in year 2000, I did not add the condition `my_data$year >= '2000'`, if you have years before 2000, just add it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. That did what I want for all columns. But it does not look like the code filled the missing values with the mean according to the country or id. I want R to look at the missing rows for country AA during the period (2000-2003) and impute the missing values if there is missing values and do the step again for another country within the same period...

Comment: Hmm, you can use the which condition, gonna update my answer.

Comment: Hisham, just updated my answer, I think now it works.

Comment: Many thanks Filipe. The previous command did work but as I explained when calculating the mean for country AA, it does not look like the mean is calculated from the available values for country AA during (2000 to 2003). I did run the updated code above and I received the following message  `There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)`.

Comment: I did not understed, you want only the data with id 'AA' betweem years 2000 and 2003 to be updated or you want all data to be updated using these conditions to calculate the mean?

Comment: Yes, dear Filipe. I want only to use the available data with id 'AA' between years 2000 and 2003 to create means for the cells with missing values "NA" and add the results in every cell that missing value. So when I have NAs in 2000 and 2001 but in 2002 and 2003 I have values, I want r to calculate the mean by using the data in 2002 and 2003 and add the result in 2000 and 2001. But I want to do thaes steps for all other ids too by using the id '  ' available data between the same years 2000 to 2003.

Comment: Updated my answer. I also add a for to iterate over all IDs.

Comment: I did run the updated code and I received the following `Error in which(merge.pisa.WDI$iso2c == iso2c & merge.pisa.WDI$year <=  : 
  object 'iso2c' not found`.

Comment: Can you please give the code to generate the data frame?

Comment: Sure, `for(id in unique(merge.pisa.WDI$iso2c))
{
  for(i in 3:ncol(merge.pisa.WDI))
  {
    merge.pisa.WDI[is.na(merge.pisa.WDI[,i]),i] <- mean(merge.pisa.WDI[which(merge.pisa.WDI$iso2c == iso2c & merge.pisa.WDI$year <= '2000'),i],na.rm = TRUE)
  }
}`.

Comment: No, the code that generate your data or the archive that you load the data data. However that’s an error, you are filtering by year <= 2000, it should be <= 2003.

Answer (score 0):

Applying a function by a column can be easily done using `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)
######creating dummy data
data=data.table(expand.grid(year=2000:2003,id=c("AA","BB","CC","DD")),
                V1=sample(c(2:4,NA),16,replace = T),
                V2=sample(c(2:4,NA),16,replace = T))


impute=function(x){
  x[is.na(x)]=mean(x,na.rm = T)
  return(x)
}
data[,lapply(.SD,impute),by=c("id")]
```

Comment: Do I replace 'data' with my data's name? In the V1=sample(c(2:4,NA) ,16,replace=T), is 2:4 the min and max number in for V1 and is it a necessary step? what does 16 represent?

Comment: That line is there just to simulate a dummy data to test the code. if your data is `my_data`, just do `data=data.table(my_data)` and then run lines after that.

Comment: I do not understand why I have an error. I got the following after running the suggested code `Error in data[, lapply(.SD, impute), by = c("id")] : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`. Please help me understand my mistake.